# Change table width bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I need to change the table width in bootstrap 4, as seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhAuk.png) the table doesn't use all the width of the page, this is the code in HTML.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="tabla">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="tabla_factura" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered  table-stripedcol text-center ">
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Vendedor</th>
            <th>Reputacion</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Vendidos</th>
            <th>Tipo de publicación</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Envio Gratis</th>
            <th>Publicacion</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `width` in the table and for the center, you can use `mx-auto` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .table {
      width: 75%;
  }
</style>

<div id="tabla">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="tabla_factura" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered  table-stripedcol text-center mx-auto">
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Vendedor</th>
            <th>Reputacion</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Vendidos</th>
            <th>Tipo de publicación</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Envio Gratis</th>
            <th>Publicacion</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!